# TextFieldParser Class

Tags: vb.net, file-io, textfieldparser

I am using the `TextFieldParser` Class to read comma separated value (.csv) file. Fields in this file are enclosed with double quotes like `"Field1","Field2"`.

So, to read file, I've set the `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` property of `TextFieldParser` object to true. But I get an error of `MalformedLineException` when any of fields contain double quote (`"+ ) in the beginning.

Example: `""Field2"with additional"` Here I should see `"Field2" with additional` as output.

However, if `"` is anywhere except first position then it works fine. 
Like line with `"Field2 "with" additional"` works perfectly fine and gives me `Field2 "with" additional` 
as output.

Does any one have same issue? Is there any way I can resolve this issue?

This is my code:

```
Private Sub ReadTextFile(ByVal txtFilePath As String)
    Dim myReader As tfp = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(txtFilePath)
    myReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    myReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    myReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
    myReader.TrimWhiteSpace = True
    Dim currentRow As String()
    Dim headerRow As Integer = 0

    While Not myReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = myReader.ReadFields()

            'Read Header
            If (headerRow = 0) Then
               'Do work for Header Row
                headerRow += 1
            Else
                'Do work for Data Row
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim errorline As String = myReader.ErrorLine
        End Try
    End While

End Sub
```

This is my Data in csv file:

```
"Column1","Column2","Column3"
"Value1","Value2",""A" Block in Building 123"
```

Comment: Looks like a bug or something. Maybe you can consider not having double quotes in your fields if they are going to be enclosed by that, if that is a possibility for you

Comment: No, I do not have control on that.

Comment: Can you add a example of the file data that is giving error?

Comment: The two consecutive double quotes look like an empty string to the parser.  Tough cookies.  All you could do is set HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = False and remove the leading and trailing double quote yourself.

Comment: Or use [KBCsv](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/).

Comment: regarding code readability, "headerRow" is probably poorly named. It doesn't represent the headerRow at all. How about just calling it rowCount or rowIndex?

Comment: or get headers before the main loop `myReader.ReadFields()
                    While Not myReader.EndOfData`

Answer (score 9):

Your example `""A" Block"` is malformed CSV; thus, TextFieldParser has every right to reject it. The [CSV standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) says:

```
7.  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
    another double quote.  For example:

    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
```

If you encode your data correctly, i.e., ...

```
"Column1","Column2","Column3"
"Value1","Value2","""A"" Block in Building 123"
```

... TextFieldParser works fine and correctly returns `"A" Block in Building 123`.

So, the first step would be to tell the guy producing the CSV file to create a valid CSV file instead of something-that-looks-like-CSV-but-isn't.

If you cannot do that, you might want to make two passes through the file:

- Fix the file by converting it into a "valid" CSV file (for example by replacing quotes not followed or preceded by a comma by two quotes).
- Then, TextFieldParser can parse the "valid" CSV file without trouble.

Answer (score -1):

*[Original answer]*

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var file = "Test.txt";

        var r = File.ReadAllLines(file)
            .Select((i, index) => new { Line = index, Fields = i.Split(new char[] { ',' }) });

        // header
        var header = r.First();

        // do work for header
        for (int j = 0; j < header.Fields.Count(); j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", header.Fields[j].Substring(1, header.Fields[j].Length-2));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        var rows = r.Skip(1).ToList();

        // do work for rows
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows[i].Fields.Count(); j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", rows[i].Fields[j].Trim(new[] { '"' }));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Note: I'm posting in C# since the question is still being tagged with it.

*As the C# tag is gone, please refer to http://converter.telerik.com/ for help in converting the code to VB.*

***[Updated answer]***

Trying a different approach (this time, in VB.Net):

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq

Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim file__1 = "Test.txt"

        Dim r = File.ReadAllLines(file__1).[Select](Function(i, index) New With { _
            .Line = index, _
            .Fields = i.Substring(1, i.Length - 2).Split(New String() {""","""}, StringSplitOptions.None) _
        })

        ' header
        Dim header = r.First()

        ' do work for header
        For j As Integer = 0 To header.Fields.Count() - 1
            Console.Write("{0} ", header.Fields(j))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()

        Dim rows = r.Skip(1).ToList()

        ' do work for rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To rows(i).Fields.Count() - 1
                Console.Write("{0} ", rows(i).Fields(j))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: No i Can not. Because in csv there are commas (,) and quotes (") are part for data also. Split function does not work in those case. Thanks though posting a code for me. It would have completely make sense if my data have not had contain comma and quotes.

Comment: @optimusprime, how about now?